# Conditional Image Template Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and entity framework 6.  I have a `GridView` and I want the `status` column on it to show four different types of images, depending on string in that field from the database.  I want it to be done with a template.

Here is my `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStatus" runat="server" Height="184px" 
        Width="1359px"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" >
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="16pt" BackColor="#cc0000" ForeColor="Black"/>
    <RowStyle Font-Size="12pt" BackColor="#afadad" ForeColor="White"/>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#afadad" ForeColor="White" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="" SelectText="Delete" ShowSelectButton="true" ControlStyle-ForeColor="White"   />   
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status"  />    
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

How do I get the `status` column to show up with four different images, dependent on what string is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField >
        <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />                               
        <ItemTemplate>   
            <asp:Image  ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#GetImagePath(Eval("img").ToString())%>' />                  
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

And in the code behind:

```
public string GetImagePath(object value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(value))) return string.Empty;
    var x = int.Parse(value.ToString());
    return x > 0 ? "Your Image Path" : "Default Image Path";
    //Here I show two different types of images depending on int value in that field from the database you can change it to four type with if-else and also depending on string value
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception error.  I think it might be in my image pathways (the images are in the solution in a folder called images.             
            return x > 0 ? "~/images/new.png" : "~/images/completed.png";   )    Not certain though.

Comment: @wiredlime2015...Try `"/images/new.png"` instead. BTW this solution should works fine for you if your image path is correct.

Comment: It is throwing an http exception, but on this line  <asp:Image  ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#GetImagePath(Eval("img").ToString())%>' />

Comment: @wiredlime2015...What is the exception message?

Comment: @wiredlime2015...`img` in this line `Eval("img").` should be your image column in the database.

Comment: Thank you, that and changing it to be a string and not int worked.  Thank you for the help.  [          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(value))) return string.Empty;
            var x = value.ToString();
            return x == "new" ? "/images/new.jpeg" : "/images/completed.jpeg";  ]

Comment: @wiredlime2015...Yes. It should also works with string I just posted an example of how you can use it. The important part is the `aspx` code then in the `GetImagePath` method you could show your favorite image somehow you want. BTW glad I could help. :)